# Optimizing a blackbox function with binary states

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, non-linear-regression, black-box

I have a non-linear black box function, which inputs a vector(size=250) and outputs a scalar value;     `f(x) = value`.

The x variable is a vector of size 250 and has binary elements, e.g.: `x = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...]`

The result is just a scalar value and I am trying to maximize this value via a binary differential evolution algorithm. Additionally, the calculation time of `f(x)` is about 10 seconds.

Since there are $2^{250}$ different x vectors, it is really hard to find the optimizer(x) of this function. However, a result that is not the optimum but not close to it would be also still an acceptable answer.

I was thinking, if I am using the right approach here in the binary differential evolution algorithm, I would appreciate it if you would give me your comments or feedback!

- Find some meaningful starting population (size=100) for the binary evo.
- Run f(x) with this population
- Create a surrogate model (probably a simple neural network that maps the vector to the result values)
- Run the surrogate model 10000 times with a random selection of x
- Select the best-performing 100 xs from the 10000 sample
- Initialize the differential evolution with the best-performing 100 surrogate model x

Comment: Curve Fitting (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If your black-box function is a differentiable function, then you can find an optimum solution with only one trainable vector.

Suppose you have the 250 length vector $V$, use the binary step activation function (you can use sigmoid), and use $f(x)$ as your loss function (if you want to maximize the output use $\frac{1}{f(x)}$). And then learn the $V$ by backpropagation.

If your function is not differentiable I don't see any solution for that.

Comment: Do you mean that even if unknown function is un differential, 250 length vector/kernel will give approximate result?

Comment: I said it should be differentiable.